# New Instances of Decorated Instances

Tags: scala

I have a set of decorator-traits (for simplicity here only trait `T`) mixing in classes (here subclasses of `A`).

```
trait T { def i: Int }
abstract class A
type AT = A with T
class B extends A
// class C extends A
// class D extends A
// ...
```

Now I have an instance `a` of e.g. class `B` which I handle as an instance of type `AT` (together with other `A`-subclass-`AT`-instances in a `Seq[AT]`).

```
val a: AT = new B with T { val i = 8 }
```

How can I generically decorate like this:

```
def toAT(a: A, i: Int): AT = {
 // how to ???
}
```

An obvious solution I thought about is:

```
trait T { def i: Int }
abstract class A {
  def asAT(i: Int): AT
}
class B extends A {
  def asAT(ii: Int): AT = new B with T { val i = ii }
}
type AT = A with T
def toAT(a: A, i: Int): AT = a.asAT(i)
```

But I don´t want to pollute my classes `B, C, ..., Z` with a new method and there are other decorations, so for every decoration-combo I need a new method for all subclasses!
Is there a more generic way?

EDIT:
An example why I need the `toAT` method, but still with the obvious solution approach from above in terms of a `redecorated` method:

```
trait T { def b: Boolean}
type AT = A with T
abstract class A(val i: Int) {
  def changedBy(x: Int): A
  def redecorated(oldAT: AT): AT
}
class B(x: Int) extends A(x) {
  def changedBy(x: Int): A = new B(i * x) 
  def redecorated(oldAT: AT): AT = new B(i) with T { val b = oldAT.b }
}
class C(x: Int) extends A(x) {
  def changedBy(x: Int): A = new C(i * x * x) 
  def redecorated(oldAT: AT): AT = new C(i) with T { val b = oldAT.b }
}
val b = new B(1) with T { val b = true  }
val c = new C(1) with T { val b = false }
val x = 8
val res: Seq[AT] = Seq(b,c) map { at => at.changedBy(x).redecorated(at) }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can't do it.

One alternative is to use the [auto proxy plugin](https://github.com/scala-incubator/autoproxy-plugin), by [Kevin Wright](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165009/kevin-wright). See also [here](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=275135) and [here](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=275588) for more information about it.

Comment: You wont see that plugin working properly before Scala 2.9 though.  It involves synthesising new methods in existing classes based on existing type information - an especially thorny problem.  There's a lot of interesting work going on in Scala trunk right now though that should make things easier for any compiler plugin that looks to generate synthetic methods

Comment: Thanks for that interesting link. Dynamic Mixins is what I wanted.

Comment: @Kevin: I am looking forward to Scala 2.9

Comment: Since 2.9.0RC1 is now out, any news on the auto proxy plugin?

Comment: @Ceki Add @Kevin to the beginning of your comment, so that he gets notified of it.